# Unable to use short cut keys (hotKeys)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, nightwatch.js

I am writing e2e tests in NightWatch v2.1.3 using page objects.
There are list of items, and an item can be selected either by click or by hotKey of its index.

Example: second element can be selected by click or shift+2.

Following code i have written, taking reference from the [docs](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/useractions/), but it is not working

```js
browser.perform(function () {
    const actions = this.actions({async: true});
    console.log('performing hotKeys');
    actions
        .click('@option1')
        .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
        .keyDown(Keys.NUMPAD2)
        .keyUp(Keys.NUMPAD2)
        .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
});
```

Console is happening but the click and keyUp, keyDown is not working, when kept inside the `.perform` method.

What need to be fixed here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `return` keyword is important. *(silly mistake here)*
2. Use 'a', 'b', '1', '2' for normal keys (single quotes are important, even for numbers)
3. `click` is not working, inside actions api. Better use the [api click](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/click.html) instead of [userActions click](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/useractions/#available-actions-). No idea why this `click` is added under new user-actions. The documentations does not have enough examples, one need to find out through hit and trial method.

Example:

- For SHIFT + 1

```js
browser
  .pause(3000)
  .perform(function () {
    const actions = this.actions({ async: true });

    return actions
      .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
      .keyDown('1')
      .keyUp('1')
      .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
  })
  .pause(2000);
```

- For Shift + 10

*(This depends on the way feature is developed, if app need both 1 and 0 to be pressed or not)*

```js
browser
  .pause(3000)
  .perform(function () {
    const actions = this.actions({ async: true });

    return actions
      .keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
      .keyDown('1')
      .keyUp('1')
      .keyDown('0')
      .keyUp('0')
      .keyUp(Keys.SHIFT);
  })
  .pause(2000);

// keyUp('10') wont work, it is not a valid key in your keyboard
```

- For simple 'a'

*(This depends on the way feature is developed, if app need both 1 and 0 to be pressed or not)*

```js
browser
  .pause(3000)
  .perform(function () {
    const actions = this.actions({ async: true });

    return actions
      .keyDown('a')
      .keyUp('a')
  })
  .pause(2000);
```